Conditionally replace object in a JSON array in jsonb
I have a jsonb column in my table that looks like this:
[
   {
     "id": "1231-213-331",
     "name" : "Object 1 Name"
   },
   {
     "id": "4113-13-131-21",
     "name" : "Object 2 Name"
   }
]

I am passing a json object to my Postgres function:
{
  "id": "1231-213-331",
  "name" : "New Name For Object One"
}

With this, I would like to entirely replace the existing json object within the jsonb object with a matching id (which is unique).
I've tried concatenation via || and using the jsonb_set function, which apparently doesn't exist. (I'm using Postgres 15.4)
How can this be done?

What error is shown regarding the jsonb_set() function? Perhaps your parameters do not have the correct types? It should exist. Perhaps provide the code that you have tried and is not working.

@Islingre it does, the path parameter was incorrect and the last arg wasn't cast to a JSONB.

you can go with exploding array as other answers suggest or you can use jsonb_path_query_array to remove the value from the array and then concat via '||' with the value:
do $$
declare
    data jsonb;
    new_value jsonb;
begin
    data := '[
      {"id":"1231-213-331", "name":"Object 1 Name"},
      {"id":"4113-13-131-21", "name":"Object 2 Name"}
    ]';

    new_value = '{"id": "1231-213-331", "name" : "New Name For Object One"}';

    data := jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$[*] ? (@.id != $id)', new_value) || new_value;

    raise notice '%', data;
end $$;


[
    {"id": "4113-13-131-21", "name": "Object 2 Name"},
    {"id": "1231-213-331", "name": "New Name For Object One"}
]


I would find the match, turn it into a text[], and then user jsonb_set() to perform the replacement:
with invars as (
  select '[
   {
     "id": "1231-213-331",
     "name" : "Object 1 Name"
   },
   {
     "id": "4113-13-131-21",
     "name" : "Object 2 Name"
   } 
]'::jsonb as jdata, 
   '{
  "id": "1231-213-331",
  "name" : "New Name For Object One"
}'::jsonb as newobj
), findindex as (
  select ARRAY[(n - 1)::text] as jpath
    from invars i
         join lateral jsonb_array_elements(i.jdata) with ordinality e(j, n)
           on e.j->'id' = i.newobj->'id'
)
select jsonb_set(i.jdata, f.jpath, i.newobj) as result
  from findindex f
       cross join invars i;

working fiddle

Your error is because function parameters must be jsonb_set ( target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb [, create_if_missing boolean ] ). Simulating your function with an anonymous block it would be something like this
do $$
declare
 in_object jsonb; 
begin
    in_object = '{
                    "id": "1231-213-331",
                    "name" : "New Name For Object One"
                }'::jsonb; 
    update a set jsonb_column = jsonb_set(jsonb_column, jbpath, in_object)
    from (
        select id, array[(e.i-1)::text] jbpath
        from a
        , jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_column) with ordinality e(cont, i)
        where e.cont->'id' = in_object->'id') sq
    where a.id = sq.id;    
end $$;

Fiddle to test

For manipulating a jsonb value inside a PL/pgSQL code block:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsb_test (_input jsonb)
  RETURNS jsonb
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _jsb jsonb := '[{"id":"1231-213-331", "name":"New Name For Object One"}
                 , {"id":"4113-13-131-21", "name":"Object 2 Name"}]';
BEGIN
   SELECT jsonb_agg(CASE WHEN obj->>'id' = _input->>'id'
                         THEN _input  -- replace whole object
                         ELSE obj END)
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements(_jsb) obj
   INTO   _jsb;

   RETURN _jsb;
END
$func$;

fiddle
Aside: jsonb_set() works just fine in Postgres 15. We just don't need it here.
